# Re: Joomla/PHP/Java/AJAX

Tags: java, php, mysql, ajax, joomla

I am a DBA, not a web developer.  I am trying to build a complex website with Joomla.  The user page needs to be interactive without refresh.  I am not sure I am using the right words, but here goes.

Assume a user is logged in and a session is started - and we have that data along with the users IP address.

The database is crunching things from other users too, just like this one.  As the database works, it generates information to be displayed on EACH users screen in real-time, without the user clicking, without screen refresh, and without the web-page code polling the server at intervals.  In fact the user may click a different action from their screen simultaneously, so the user screen cannot be sitting waiting for a reply or polling at predefined intervals.  It is basically receiving and transmitting "virutally" at the same time.  If this is possible to do, a single piece of code would work and results could be deciphered for the right screen entry point (several boxes).

What can be used to do this?  Thanks, Bruce

Comment: What you are looking for is probably websockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/. These provide the ability to maintain a connection between the server and the browser, so you aren't dependent on the browser pinging the server, but instead allows the server to push information to the browser. This is how a chat program would typically work.

Answer (score 0):

off cource its possible. make ajax call to link like

```
"index.php?controller=myController"
```

and in myController set header of either xml or json and prepare response of AJAX there. and at end of code write $app->close(); to avoide rendering of other modules and content